# Error en de agrupar items con pipes con observable list Angular

Tags: angular, angularjs

tengo un problema con agrupar con pipes elementos de una lista que tienen el mismo nombre esta linea

```
 this.cartService.cart$
```

es un observable que contiene una lista de productos pero al momento de realizar el agrupar no puedo devolver el observable , por favor si me pueden dar una ayuda.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {product} from './../../../product.model';
import {CartService} from './../../../core/services/cart.service';
import { Observable,from} from 'rxjs';
import { groupBy, mergeMap, toArray, reduce} from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-order',
  templateUrl: './order.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order.component.scss']
})
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {
  products$: Observable<product[]>;
  list : product[];

  constructor(
    private cartService: CartService,
    
  ) {
    
 

      this.products$ = this.cartService.cart$.forEach(
        item=>{
          from(item).pipe(groupBy(person=>person.title), 
          mergeMap(group =>  group.pipe(toArray()))
    
    ) } );
   }
```

Comment: Por que haces subscripciones de los productos que recibes en el servicio?

Comment: los realizo para obtener los items que tengo en el servicio   o se tendria que realizar otra cosa ?

Comment: Puedes poner el código de `.$cart`?. Y una pequeña muestra de los datos que te da? Y has un `console.log(item)`. Todo lo pones en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente es asi:

```js
this.products$ = this.cartService.cart$.subscribe(
  items => {
    console.log(items)
  });
```

`